# Select one column with where clause Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Im using Eloquent. But I'm having trouble understanding Eloquent syntax. I have been searching, and trying this cheat sheet: http://cheats.jesse-obrien.ca, but no luck.

## How do i perform this SQL query?

`SELECT user_id FROM notes WHERE note_id = 1`

Thanks!

Comment: That SQL query is entirely invalid, as it lacks a `FROM` clause.

Comment: Chances are you want something like `Model::select('user_id')->whereNoteId(1)->get()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 'note_id' is the primary key on your model, you can simply use:

```
Note::find(1)->user_id
```

Otherwise, you can use any number of syntaxes:

```
Note::where('note_id', 1)->first()->user_id;
Note::select('user_id')->where('note_id', 1)->first(); 
Note::whereNoteId(1)->first();
// or get() will give you multiple results if there are multiple
```

Also note, in any of these examples, you can also just assign the entire object to a variable and just grab the user_id attribute when needed later.

```
$note = Note::find(1);
// $user_id = $note->user_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a single record then use

```
Note::where('note_id','1')->first(['user_id']);
```

and for more than one record use

```
Note::where('note_id','1')->get(['user_id']);
```